# Fastest way to create strictly increasing lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, scipy

I would like to find out what is the most efficient way to achieve the following in Python:

Suppose we have two lists `a` and `b` which are of equal length and contain up to 1e7 elements.
However, for the ease of illustration we may consider the following:

```
a = [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 8,10,11]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

The goal is to create a strictly monotonic list `a_new` from `a` whereas only the first sample point of sample points with identical values is used.
The same indices that have to be deleted in `a` should also be deleted in `b` such that the final result will be:

```
a_new = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11]
b_new = [1, 4, 5, 6, 8,10,11,12,14,15]
```

Of course this can be done using computationally expensive `for` loops which is however not suitable due to the huge amount of data.

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: Thank's a lot for all contributions which are all significatly faster than a classic for-loop approach. I upvoted all solutions since I really liked them and they all do work. The solution of @piRSquared turned out to be the fastest one. Therefore I will accept his answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running a version of @juanpa.arrivillaga's function with `numba`

```
import numba

def psi(A):
    a_cummax = np.maximum.accumulate(A)
    a_new, idx = np.unique(a_cummax, return_index=True)
    return idx

def foo(arr):
    aux=np.maximum.accumulate(arr)
    flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1]))
    return np.nonzero(flag)[0]

@numba.jit
def f(A):
    m = A[0]
    a_new, idx = [m], [0]
    for i, a in enumerate(A[1:], 1):
        if a > m:
            m = a
            a_new.append(a)
            idx.append(i)
    return idx
```

---

***timing***

```
%timeit f(a)
The slowest run took 5.37 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 µs per loop

%timeit foo(a)
The slowest run took 9.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.35 µs per loop

%timeit psi(a)
The slowest run took 9.66 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.95 µs per loop
```

Comment: Wow. That is a significant improvement. I might try it out with `Cython` when I get home.

Comment: Could you post the timing results as text rather than a picture of text? Your answer looks interesting but I'm having trouble reading the results.

Comment: @Cornstalks I'm on a plane at the moment. I can't. However results were 1.8 microseconds for numba, 6.3 microseconds for hpauljs foo, and 9.9 microseconds for psidoms

Comment: Also, note, this is not taking advantage of the single pass like my original solution. `A[1:]` copies almost the entire list, essentially. You should iterate over `for i, a in enumerate(A, i)` and just use the `float('-inf')` trick.

Comment: @Cornstalks: click that image to see it at a more reasonable size

Comment: I got similar results during timing of the method calls. So numba seems to be the way to go!

Comment: Could you provide timings for bigger arrays? Whenever `%timeit` prints that warning you shouldn't (completly) trust that timing.

Answer (score 14):

You can calculate the cumulative max of `a` and then drop duplicates with `np.unique` with which you can also record the unique index so as to subset `b` correspondingly:

```
a = np.array([2,1,2,3,4,5,4,6,5,7,8,9,8,10,11])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])

a_cummax = np.maximum.accumulate(a)    
a_new, idx = np.unique(a_cummax, return_index=True)

a_new
# array([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

b[idx]
# array([ 1,  4,  5,  6,  8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15])
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a vanilla Python solution that does one pass:

```
>>> a = [2,1,2,3,4,5,4,6,5,7,8,9,8,10,11]
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
>>> a_new, b_new = [], []
>>> last = float('-inf')
>>> for x, y in zip(a, b):
...     if x > last:
...         last = x
...         a_new.append(x)
...         b_new.append(y)
...
>>> a_new
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> b_new
[1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15]
```

I'm curious to see how it compares to the `numpy` solution, which will have similar time complexity but does a couple of passes on the data.

Here are some timings. First, setup:

```
>>> small = ([2,1,2,3,4,5,4,6,5,7,8,9,8,10,11], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
>>> medium = (np.random.randint(1, 10000, (10000,)), np.random.randint(1, 10000, (10000,)))
>>> large = (np.random.randint(1, 10000000, (10000000,)), np.random.randint(1, 10000000, (10000000,)))
```

And now the two approaches:

```
>>> def monotonic(a, b):
...     a_new, b_new = [], []
...     last = float('-inf')
...     for x,y in zip(a,b):
...         if x > last:
...             last = x
...             a_new.append(x)
...             b_new.append(y)
...     return a_new, b_new
...
>>> def np_monotonic(a, b):
...     a_new, idx = np.unique(np.maximum.accumulate(a), return_index=True)
...     return a_new, b[idx]
...
```

Note, the approaches are not strictly equivalent, one stays in vanilla Python land, the other stays in `numpy` array land. We will compare performance assuming you are starting with the corresponding data structure (either `numpy.array` or `list`):

So first, a small list, the same from the OP's example, we see that `numpy` is not actually faster, which isn't surprising for small data structures:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("monotonic(a,b)", "from __main__ import monotonic, small; a, b = small", number=10000)
0.039130652003223076
>>> timeit.timeit("np_monotonic(a,b)", "from __main__ import np_monotonic, small, np; a, b = np.array(small[0]), np.array(small[1])", number=10000)
0.10779813499539159
```

Now a "medium" list/array of 10,000 elements, we start to see `numpy` advantages:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("monotonic(a,b)", "from __main__ import monotonic, medium; a, b = medium[0].tolist(), medium[1].tolist()", number=10000)
4.642718859016895
>>> timeit.timeit("np_monotonic(a,b)", "from __main__ import np_monotonic, medium; a, b = medium", number=10000)
1.3776302759943064
```

Now, interestingly, the advantage seems to narrow with "large" arrays, on the order of 1e7 elements:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("monotonic(a,b)", "from __main__ import monotonic, large; a, b = large[0].tolist(), large[1].tolist()", number=10)
4.400254560023313
>>> timeit.timeit("np_monotonic(a,b)", "from __main__ import np_monotonic, large; a, b = large", number=10)
3.593393853981979
```

Note, in the last pair of timings, I only did them 10 times each, but if someone has a better machine or more patience, please feel free to increase `number`

Comment: From my overall experience C-compiled-modules are from 10 to 100 times faster than pure Python, so I bet the numpy solution will be faster ... Curious if I am right. Hope the OP will provide the results of timing.

Comment: @Claudio In my experience, with `numpy` arrays vs vanilla Python list, the advantages in speed for simple operations like this aren't always straightforward, and depend on the size of your data structures. Check out the edit I just added, where I show timings for different sized data structures.

Answer (score 10):

`unique` with `return_index` uses `argsort`.  With `maximum.accumulate` that isn't needed.  So we can cannibalize `unique` and do:

```
In [313]: a = [2,1,2,3,4,5,4,6,5,7,8,9,8,10,11]
In [314]: arr = np.array(a)
In [315]: aux = np.maximum.accumulate(arr)
In [316]: flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1])) # key unique step
In [317]: idx = np.nonzero(flag)
In [318]: idx
Out[318]: (array([ 0,  3,  4,  5,  7,  9, 10, 11, 13, 14], dtype=int32),)
In [319]: arr[idx]
Out[319]: array([ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
In [320]: np.array(b)[idx]
Out[320]: array([ 1,  4,  5,  6,  8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15])

In [323]: np.unique(aux, return_index=True)[1]
Out[323]: array([ 0,  3,  4,  5,  7,  9, 10, 11, 13, 14], dtype=int32)
```

---

```
def foo(arr):
    aux=np.maximum.accumulate(arr)
    flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1]))
    return np.nonzero(flag)[0]

In [330]: timeit foo(arr)
....
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 µs per loop
In [331]: timeit np.unique(np.maximum.accumulate(arr), return_index=True)[1]
....
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.5 µs per loop
```

With (10000,) shape `medium` this sort-less unique has a substantial speed advantage:

```
In [334]: timeit np.unique(np.maximum.accumulate(medium[0]), return_index=True)[1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 351 µs per loop
In [335]: timeit foo(medium[0])
The slowest run took 4.14 times longer ....
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.9 µs per loop
```

[1]: Use `np.source(np.unique)` to see code, or ?? in IPython

Comment: you're not timing it both the same way. function call overhead is there in first case

Comment: @kmario23 a single function call wouldn't cause those differences.

Comment: What's left to do is slice the arrays.  `np.nonzero` returns the indices of where the dups are... just like `np.unique` with `return_index=True`

Comment: Just for the fun of it I profiled the `np.unique` solution with the large random data: `cumtime:` `np_monotonic: 493ms` `cummax: 47ms` `unique: 433ms` of which the pointless `argsort: 292ms`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 8,10,11]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
print(sorted(set(a)))
print(sorted(set(b)))
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't match the requirements listed in the question. As you're answering a three year old question with accepted answer you may want to consider whether your answer adds value.