# Slice a list in python

Tags: python, slice

I have a list in python like:

```
l = [1,2,4,5,7,8,2,1]
```

I want a code that will check if the number before in the list is bigger that the next one. And if it is i want the code to remove the the number. I want my code to return `[1,2,4,5,7,8]` and remove the **last 2 and 1**.

Pseudo code:

```
If l[i] > l[i+1]
remove l[i+1]
then check if l[i] is bigger than the next one after that. What use to be l[i+2]
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Should `[1,2,5,2,4]` return `[1,2,5,4]` because `4>2` or `[1,2,5]` because `4<5`?

Comment: Should `[10, 11, 1, 12]` result in `[10, 11]` or `[10, 11, 12]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to create strictly increasing lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577744/fastest-way-to-create-strictly-increasing-lists-in-python)

Comment: What should `[10,9,8,11,12,13]` return?

Answer (score 1):

Started with your list and appended based upon your criteria to a new one.

```
l = [1,2,4,5,7,8,2,1]

result = [] 
chk = 0 

for num in l:

  if chk > num:
    pass
  else:
    chk = num
    result.append(num)

print result
```

Apparently it is bad practice to delete entries from lists within a loop , so this is a workaround.

Comment: `list(l)` is not necessary. Just `for num in l:` works.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through array if there is array[i] > array[i+1] then remove array[i+1].

```
array = [1,2,4,5,7,8,2,1]
l = len(array)

first = 0
secound = 1

while secound != l:
    if array[first] > array[secound]:
        del array[secound]
        l -= 1
    else:
        first += 1
        secound += 1

print(array)
```

Comment: Lists and arrays are different structures. Your terminology can be perceived as being a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find areas of lists that fulfill a condition; in this case, each number is larger than the number proceeding:

```
from itertools import groupby 

l = [1,2,4,5,7,8,2,1]

for k, g in groupby(enumerate(l[1:],1), key=lambda (i,e): e>l[i-1]):
    if k:
        grp=list(g)
        print l[grp[0][0]-1:grp[-1][0]+1]
        # [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

This will find any area in the list that meets that condition:

```
l = [1,2,4,5,7,8,2,5]

for k, g in groupby(enumerate(l[1:],1), key=lambda (i,e): e>l[i-1]):
    if k:
        grp=list(g)
        print l[grp[0][0]-1:grp[-1][0]+1]
        # prints [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8] and [2, 5]
```

So break after the first if you only want 1 group:

```
l = [10, 11, 12, 1, 2]
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(l[1:],1), key=lambda (i,e): e>l[i-1]):
    if k:
        grp=list(g)
        print l[grp[0][0]-1:grp[-1][0]+1]
        break
        # [10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this even in one line:

```
     l = l[0:1] + [el for index,el in enumerate(l[0:])  if el >l[index-1]]
     #l[0:1] + is ugly but i couldnt figure out another way to get the
     #first element since in python l[-1] = l[len(l)-1]
```